# Optimize split data from array in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array what looks like

```
array(
[0]array(
    [asoc_key1]=>value,
    [asoc_key2]=>value),
[1]array(
    [asoc_key1]=>value,
    [asoc_key2]=>value),
....
)
```

I need split unique asoc_key1 values into one array and unique values from `asoc_key2` into second. My code looks like this:

```
    foreach ($bloggersInfo as $bloggerInfo) {
        $categoryIdArray[] = $bloggerInfo['category_id'];
        $mozdaArray[] = $bloggerInfo['mozda'];
    }
    $categoryIdArray = array_values(array_unique($categoryIdArray));
    $mozdaArray = array_values(array_unique($mozdaArray));
```

Is there way to optimize this code?

Comment: Post your original array along with expected output and from your code it seems you need something like `array_unqiue(array_column($array,'category_id'))`

Comment: meanwhile I wish to add that php version on production is 5.2

Comment: Post the values of `$categoryIdArray` and `$mozdaArray`

Comment: $categoryIdArray -is array that has values with type int in range from 1 to 100(1,15,6,32); $mozdaArray - is array that has values with type float in range from 0 to 100(50.67, 84.57, 67.34)

Comment: Simply use `array_unique($categoryIdArray,'SORT_REGULAR')`

Comment: your solution giving me error: Message: array_unique() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given. And result is NULL...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83862/discussion-between-oleg-sapishchuk-and-uchiha).

Comment: Oh yeah my bad `array_unique($categoryIdArray,SORT_REGULAR)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `array_column` function. Your solution might be

```
$categoryIdArray = array_unqiue(array_column($bloggersInfo,'category_id'));
$mozdaArray = array_unqiue(array_column($bloggersInfo,'mozda'));
if (! function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column(array $input, $columnKey) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($input as $value) {
            $array[] = $value[$columnKey];
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: php version on production is 5.2 so it's a bit impossible to use your solution, but thanks.

Comment: If `array_column` not works then you can write your own function try edited solution.

Comment: Writing array_column function with php is not performance solution in this situation. As it will take more time and memory usage according to my solution in this post.